# Python: Sorting lists of dictionaries that contain lists of other dictionaries based on length of a member in the nested dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

An example of my data structure looks like this:

*main list*:

`[{..}, {..}, ..] # list of dictionaries`

*main list* stores *list element dicts*:

```
{
'queues': [{..}, {..}, ..],  # list of more dictionaries
}
```

*inner list element dict*:

```
{
'member': ["string", "string", ..] # list of strings
}
```

My goal is to sort *main list* based on the length of the *member list* in the inner dictionaries.
What's an efficient and pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are multiple such `member` lists in each element of the main list. Which one is the relevant one? Or do you want to sum over the lengthes of all those member lists to get the sort key?

Comment: It sounds like there's several member lists, i.e. `main["queues"][0]["member"], main["queues"][1]["member"], main["queues"][2]["member"], ...`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `key` argument of the `sorted` function and `list.sort` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `sorted` or `list.sort` with an appropriate key function.
If you sort by the total length of all `member` lists:

```
main_list.sort(key=lambda d: sum(len(x['member']) for x in d['queues']))
```

Or if you want to always consider only the first one relevant:

```
main_list.sort(key=lambda d: len(d['queues'][0]['member']))
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I had an error in my lambda expression.